# Video header works only on previews, but not on published pages

Tags: videos, video-header

I've made a video header for a customers website, I found out that video is not loading when I am not logged to admin of WordPress, or watching the page from Preview. I already tried another video hosting mp4 servers, I tried to make a video file smaller, as well as I tried to debug few things, but still no solution.

Could anybody help me? The video is supposed to load on the Home page right under the navigation bar.

Link for web is www.interwood.sk

Comment: Where is the code?

  And it's a bad practice to give a site address where HTML is compressed and unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I haven't realised I made a compress. Actually right now I found a solution. It was in bad server where I hosted a video. As I tried to use jwplayer for hosting, it works absolutely perfect. :)